# How can I prevent my website from displaying WebP images on unsupported browsers?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have identified an issue with my WordPress website, where it attempts to display WebP images on unsupported browsers. As a result, the images appear broken when accessed from these unsupported browsers. I suspect that this issue is caused by a problem with the `.htaccess` rule. Can someone provide guidance on how to fix this issue?

The following is the `.htaccess` rule related to the display of WebP images on my website:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "image/webp"
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone.*Version/(\d{2}).*Safari
RewriteCond %1 >13
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what that configuration you posted actually does?

Comment: How are you currently managing the display of (WebP) images? What URLs are you linking to? Do the same images exist in both `.webp` and `.jpg` (or `.png`)? "The following is the `.htaccess` rule related to the display of WebP images" - but that doesn't really do anything; all that does is set an environment variable (related to caching). Any other directives in `.htaccess`? Maybe WP itself is supposed to be managing this, or not at all? More information is needed to be able to answer this...

Comment: _Aside:_ You format code blocks by indenting 4 spaces (use the button on the editor toolbar) or use backtick fencing (all the information is in the editor). Don't use backslash-escape's all over your code in an attempt at formatting!

Comment: Can't tell what your envvars are meant to do, but if the older safari versions have the accept header w/ webp, you will still have set the envvars even though you're trying to make it conditional on the major version