# How can I prevent WebP images from appearing on unsupported browsers and display JPEG or PNG images instead on my WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, webp

I've been having trouble with my WordPress website lately. It seems that the WebP images are appearing broken on unsupported browsers, and I can't figure out why. I'm guessing that it might have something to do with the .htaccess rule. Can anyone help me out with this? Below is the .htaccess rule I'm currently using to display WebP images on my website:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "image/webp"

RewriteRule .\* - \[E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp\]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone.\*Version/(\\d{2}).*Safari

RewriteCond %1 \>13

RewriteRule .* - \[E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp\]
```

I am attempting to display PNG or JPG images as a fallback option for unsupported browsers, but I have been unsuccessful in my attempts. Despite my efforts, the WebP images continue to appear broken on unsupported browsers. I am seeking guidance on how to successfully display PNG or JPG images as a fallback option on my WordPress website.

Comment: Already asked here, [How can I prevent my website from displaying WebP images on unsupported browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76242145/how-can-i-prevent-my-website-from-displaying-webp-images-on-unsupported-browsers)